# Using Matlab to average daily data (rasters) to monthly averages

Tags: matlab

I have 2192 rasters representing daily timestep climate data (1 jan 2008-31 mar 2013), which I would like to aggregate into monthly means (i.e average all the data within a given month&year).

I can load the data into Matlab fine to create a 3D matrix, of size 110x57x2192. The 2192 represents time dimension from jan 2008-31 to 31 mar 2013.

I have tried this using numbering in excel, but I am not sure how to set the syntax right. The monthly means should idealy replace the imported daily data in the memory. My numbering in Excel has four columns: date,day, month and year. Any NA pixel is ignored and the average for the pixel based on non NA pixels for a given month.

```
%create monthly averages from daily data
numbering = xlsread('Numbering.xslx', B1:D2192);
month=numbering(:,2);
years=unique(year);
```

Here is the first three and last three row of my excel file for numbering

1/01/2008   1   1   2008
2/01/2008   2   1   2008
3/01/2008   3   1   2008
29/12/2013  29  12  2013
30/12/2013  30  12  2013
31/12/2013  31  12  2013
31/12/2013  31  12  2013

Comment: Is it really date,month and year or **day**, month and year that you have in your Excel?

Comment: Note that the data is not in excel, rather in the above code I am attempting to use excel to create an index. The excel file has 4 columns d/m/yy; day, month and year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would tackle the problem:

```
% Getting month breaks by detecting changes in days
day=numbering(:,2); % Day column from Excel
final_idx = find(diff(day)~=1);
initial_idx = [1 ; final_idx(1:end-1)-1];

%Number of months
nom = length(final_idx);

% Pre-allocating space for monthly mean
monthlymeans = nan(110,57,nom);

% Calculating means
for ii=1:nom
    monthlymeans(:,:,ii) = nanmean(3dmatrix(:,:,initial_idx(ii):final_idx(ii)),3);
end
```

Note that I assumed the data is contained in a variable called 3dmatrix and the NA pixel values are actually NaN's, since I do not have access to your original data.

Comment: >> day=numbering(:,1);
    final_idx = diff(day)~=1;
    initial_idx = [1 final_idx(1:end-1)-1]; Error using horzcat
    
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: the line with initial_idx triggers an error. also in the workspace, the dimension for 'nom' is 2191, which is the number of days. I did not get to calulating means as the initial_idx did not work. just incase it has to do with my my excel, column A is m/d/y;B is day, C is month and D is year. The sporeadsheet has no header.

Comment: ps. the NA pixel values are NaN's; the data is contained in a 3D matrix (3dmatrix as you called it), the time dimension is days.

Comment: day should be the days column from your excel (B), I adjusted that. The dimension of nom should be close to 2192/30. Also I changed a detail in the 4th line, I hope it gets rid of the horzcat. The fact that you already have nans in the matrix makes things easier

Comment: with the latest edits, horzcat is gone, however, dimensions still aren't right. nom dimension is still 2191, Further, there seems so be an error in the last section as follows:    Warning: Colon operands should not be logical. 
   Warning: Colon operands should not be logical. 
   Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add a function I used in the workspace. The indexes should not be logical. That will also fix the dimension differences. Try again with the *find* function added

Comment: Appreciate it mate, but same problem. nom is now a single value of 2125; initial_idx has a dimension of 2125 x 1; day has 2192 x 1. Also I don't see function find in the revision

Comment: It's in the final idx definition. It will change quite a lot of things. One question... are the days ordered? It is something I assumed but forgot to mention. I used a dummy variable called days = [1:31 1:28 1:31 1:30]; to try to answer your example. The idea was to find month changes using the days. If they are not ordered other approach will be necessary

Comment: In the day Column B, day entries are a product of excel function day(Column A) which is a date column. Does the ascript assume day numbering 1-2192?

Comment: So when I run the entire script replacing 3dmatrix with my matrix, here is the error message: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: Also please see the sample table above

Comment: My bad. I was reading in excel from column B as follows:  `numbering = xlsread('NumberingMaina.xlsx','B1:D2192');`  therefore I needed to adjust the first line of your code. This works great!

Comment: Glad it helped mate! Consider accepting as an answer if you will so others that stumble upon the same problem might benefit from it!